# Simulation RStudio

Tags: r, simulation

I'm using package fGarch in R to simulate a skewed normal distribution.
The statistics I have are as follows:

Mean = 155

Sd = 35

Median = 150

I used the formula: (3*(mean-median))/sd to calculate skewness which came out to 0.427857
I used the following code:

```
x <- rsnorm(10000,mean = 155,sd=35,xi=0.427857)
plot(density(x))
```

However, the plot showed was negatively skewed even though my skewness parameter was positive.
I ran the code a few times to ensure it wasn't a one-time thing.
I can't seem to find the error (since I expected it to be positively skewed). Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many definitions for skewness, such as the one you used [Pearson's second skewness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness). The skewness `Xi` in `fGarch` is based on a paper (Fernandez & Steel 2000), and is an inverse scale factor in the positive and the negative directions.

As shown in the figure below, inverting skewness `Xi` produces the mirror image around zero. When `Xi` = 1, the distribution is symmetrical. When 0 < `Xi` < 1, negative skew. When `Xi` > 1, positive skew.

[image]

In your example, the Mean is skewed to the right of the Median. So we're looking for a positive skew (`Xi` > 1). By trial and error, the `Xi` could be located around *1.094095* . The median value given by the quantile function `qsnorm(0.5, Mean, Sd, xi=1.094095)` is indeed 150.

The simulated median is however a bit biased, which results in an unexpected Pearson's second skewness.

```
Mean <- 155
Sd <- 35
Median <- 150
3 * (Mean - Median) / Sd #Pearson's second skewness
#0.4285714

library(fGarch)
set.seed(1)
x <- rsnorm(100000, Mean, Sd, xi=1.094095)

mean(x)
#154.9353
sd(x)
#35.07564
median(x) #a bit higher than expected
#153.9029
3 * (mean(x) - median(x)) / sd(x) #biased from expected
#0.08830281
```

Finally, the code for locating `Xi` using General-purpose Optimization `optim` method.

```
fn <- function(log_Xi, Mean, Sd, Median) {
  abs(qsnorm(0.5, Mean, Sd, exp(log_Xi)) - Median)
  }

tem <- optim(0, fn, gr=NULL, Mean, Sd, Median)
Xi <- exp(tem$par)
#1.094095
```

And the code for the density plot above.

```
x_ <- seq(-5,5, by=0.01)
plot(x_, dsnorm(x_, xi=3), type='l', ylab='density', col='red', xlab='x', main='Skewness')
lines(x_, dsnorm(x_, xi=1), col='black', lty=2)
lines(x_, dsnorm(x_, xi=1/3), col='blue')
legend('topright', legend=c('3','1','1/3'), fill=c('red','black','blue'), title='Xi')
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It explains the problems I had....